# git diff for *.cpp files prints nothing in one repository

Tags: linux, git, diff

Once the command `git diff *.cpp` just stopped printing anything in one repository, despite `git diff *.h` works fine. `git diff` works fine for *.cpp files.

What could it be?

Comment: Does it work correctly as `git diff -- '*.cpp'`? What does `echo *.cpp` print?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, `git diff '*.cpp'` gives correct result. `echo *.cpp` prints only one .cpp file placed in the repository root directory, while `echo '*.cpp'` works fine. If I delete that .cpp file in the root, `git diff *.cpp` works fine again. So I should move the file from the root, or may be I will find some settings to avoid typing apostrophes every time, as I use this command alot. Or I will just get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to be careful to run, e.g.:

```
git diff '*.cpp'
```

or:

```
git diff \*.cpp
```

or more formally:

```
git diff -- '*.cpp'
```

or similar.

#### What's going on here?

Missing from the question: the desired output was a diff for `subdir/subfile.cpp`, but the top level of the work-tree contained one file named `file.cpp` or similar.

The problem stems from the fact that you're using a Unix/Linux-style shell, which expands `*` and other wildcard or [*glob*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) characters *before* running the command you enter at the command line.  But there is a bit of subtlety here as well.

Because there exists a file named `file.cpp` in the current directory, when you run:

```
git diff *.cpp
```

the *shell* replaces `*.cpp` with the names of all the files whose name ends with `.cpp`, and therefore runs:

```
git diff file.cpp
```

Git then dutifully produces the diff—or in this case, *no* diff since there is no difference—for the one file named `file.cpp`.

When there are *no* files named `file.cpp` or `zorg.cpp` or similar in the top level directory, however, this shell simply invokes `git` with arguments `diff` and `*.cpp`, as if you had quoted the asterisk.  This gives *Git* the chance to expand the `*.cpp` argument, and when *Git* expands it, it does so in a different way than the shell.

#### Why use `--`?

The `git diff` command takes a number of options, such as `-s`, `-p`, `-w`, `--name-status`, `--name-only`, and so on.

Depending on what files you have, suppose you want a diff listing for the file named `-z` in the current directory.  If you then run:

```
git diff -z
```

Git thinks you mean to supply the `-z` *option*, rather than to get a diff listing for the file named `-z`.  A similar problem applies if you want diffs for `-z*` and the like.

In general, you can work around this problem by using the file name `./-z` instead of just `-z`.  Since `./-z` does not start with `-`, Git is not fooled into thinking it's an option.  But this problem is more general, and strikes in other cases (other commands) as well.  For instance, suppose you have a *file* named `develop` and you run:

```
git checkout develop
```

Git will think you mean to check out the *branch* named `develop`.

All Git commands accept `--` as a *separator*, generally meaning *there no more options: anything after this point is an argument instead*.  For `git diff`, anything after `--` is treated as a *pathspec*, which includes doing glob expansion, provided the glob characters made it past the shell.

This is what the syntax description in [the SYNOPSIS section of the `git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_synopsis) means:

```
git diff [<options>] [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
git diff [<options>] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
git diff [<options>] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
git diff [<options>] <blob> <blob>
git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>
```

The square brackets indicate that something is optional, so all the options are optional.  The angle brackets indicate that some argument should be replaced with a string that meets the requirements of the type inside the brackets.  The literal `--` or other literal options imply that you should type those characters literally—so `git diff --cached` requires the literal string `--cached`, for instance.  Last, the `...` means "repeat the previous as often as you like".

Since the literal string `--` is optional, you don't have to enter it—but if you do, everything *after* it must have the form of a `<path>`.  That form is quite general: almost any character is valid.  The documentation is missing a cross-reference to the definition of a *pathspec*, though (and probably should use `<pathspec>`, not just `<path>`, here).  The full description of pathspecs is in [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

Answer (score 0):

So I have one .cpp file in the repository root directory, and so `git diff *.cpp` now prints changes only for this file, while `git diff '*.cpp'` works fine for all files in subdirectories.